# Can't figure out the exact function requirement

Tags: graphing-functions

I need a function which is roughly (but not exactly) equivalent to $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
As $x$ varies from $0$ to $100$, $f(x)$ should vary from $20$ to $0$.
Rough indications for values are as follows, to give an idea and know if I know things right:

\begin{array}{c|*5c}  
x&     4&    11&    20&    50&    80\\ \hline
f(x) &18 &  15 &   12 &   5  &    2
\end{array} 
I am completely out of touch of maths. Please if someone can at least guide me in the right direction. I have filled several pages of notebook and now I'm getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac{(x-100)^2}{500}$ works pretty well. It's a parabola with its vertex at $(100,0)$  such that $f(0) = 20$.

Comment: Damn my weak maths. Thnx.